# Get count in a projection

Tags: breeze

Suppose that I want to show a list of Customers with the count of orders but i don't want to get all the orders, only the count.

I know that i can do a special method in the webapi controller that returns the customer collection with the count of orders, but Is there a way to do it from javascript with a projection?

Something like:

EntityQuery.from("Customers").select("Customer, Customer.Orders.Count")

Answer (score 0, accepted):

AFAIK, there is no Breeze syntax (and no OData query syntax) that does what you want. I think you'll have to add the special server method.

If you **HAVE** to define the customer projection on the client (perhaps the user can make an *ad hoc* selection of Customer properties) **AND** you need the order count too, we can talk. That would require some tricky server-side magic but it can be done. Don't ask unless you really, really need it :).

Comment: Ward doesn't OData return an inline count ? Could that be used , seems the question hints at some kind of paging requirement

Comment: That's the inline count for the primary objects returned ... which in this case is the number of Customer-projections returned, not the desired number of orders-per-customer

Comment: I don't need it now so better to not ask ;) 
Although knowledge does not take place.